# Knockout-3.2.0 - Inner list<object> push issue

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am Using knockout.js for an asp application.
I have a list of objects returned by the controller action to the view, furthermore those objects in the list points to a list of objects. I am not being able to add the new objects to the inner list through knockout. What i have done so far is:

```
@{
     var initialData = @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization
                                  .JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
 }
```

and in viewmodel:

```
LineItemFields = ko.observableArray(@initialData );
```

add function in viewmodel does the following:

```
 addLineItem = function () {
   ko.utils.arrayForEach(ko.toJS(LineItemFields), function (item) {
     item.LineItemValues.push({"FieldValue": "0", "configseqid": 0, "FieldID": 0,
                               "isVisible": true, "isUpdatable": true });
   });

//LineItemValues is the inner list of each object being iterated.
```

I tried debugging the script and it successfully pushes a new item to the innerlist of object being iterated but not in the original object. Meaning item.LineItemValues is a copy and not LineItemFields[index].LineItemValues, what can i do more so that the new item should be pushed in the observable array?

Update: My template binding and script is:

```
 <tr data-bind="template: {name: 'LineItemDataTemplate', foreach: LineItemFields}"> </tr>

 <script id="LineItemDataTemplate" type="text/html">
        <td data-bind="foreach: $data['LineItemValues']"><input type="text" data-bind="value: FieldValue, enable: $parent.isUpdatable" /></td>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ko.toJS()`will create plain js copy of the `observableArray`. You need to use the original array which is wrapped inside that observable array:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(LineItemFields(), function (item) {
    item.LineItemValues.push({ "FieldValue": "0", "configseqid": 0, "FieldID": 0,
                               "isVisible": true, "isUpdatable": true });
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't update anything. Tried removing ko.toJS(), it pushes the elements in item.LineItemValues but doesn't reflect any change on UI. As LineItemFields() is observable so it should!

Comment: You are changing `LineItemFields` elements property (`LineItemValues`) not `LineItemFields` itself, so there is no notification (observableArray only watches for elements add/remove to the array, not if they changed). You need to transform `item.LineItemValues` to observableArray to see the change.

Comment: I updated the template which is bind to this observable array (LineItemFields)

Comment: It finally worked. I changed the type of inner lists to string and attached observables with them. Added following in my viewModel:

     ko.utils.arrayForEach(LineItemFields(), function (item) {
                    item.LineItemValues = ko.observableArray(item.LineItemValues);
                })